# Positioning axis labels

Tags: ios, swiftui, charts

This is the x-axis of a SwiftUI Chart:

[image]

As you can see the vertical gridlines cross the x-axis and the labels (1,735 etc) are drawn to the right of the lines.

I would like the gridlines to stop at the x-axis and have the labels centered below it.

Is that possible?

I am now using the following modifiers:

```
.chartXAxisLabel(position: .bottom, alignment: .center) {
    Text("x axis title")
}
.chartXScale(domain: [minX, maxX])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `.chartXAxis` modifier to define the `AxisMarks`:

- include `AxisGridLine` to have the lines included
- omit `AxisTick` if you don't want axis ticks below the grid lines
- set an anchor of `.top` for the labels.

Like this:

```swift
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(position: .bottom, values: .automatic) { _ in
        AxisGridLine()
        AxisValueLabel(anchor: .top)
    }
}
```

See [Customizing axes in Swift Charts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/customizing-axes-in-swift-charts) for detailed documentation.